# Confused about basic SQL schema table issue

Tags: sql

If a person can have as hobby as many sports as he wants, and every sports can be seen as a hobby by as many persons as possible, how can you create a db schema table for it?

Comment: With this much reputation you should know how to write a *good* question by now ....

Comment: Happy to help beginners, but we really do need to ask for _some_ prior effort.

Comment: Sorry, I was in a real rush and I haven't done SQL for years...thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple many-to-many realtionship:

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
    ID       INTEGER       PRIMARY KEY,
    Name     VARCHAR(50)   NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Sport
(
    ID       INTEGER       PRIMARY KEY,
    Sport    VARCHAR(50)   NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Hobby 
(
    PersonID       INTEGER,
    SportID        INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(PersonID,SportID),
    FOREIGN KEY(PersonID) REFERENCES Person(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(SportID) REFERENCES Sport(ID),
)
```

Comment: you just had to one-up me with the `create-table` syntax, didn't ya :)